# DDD - Should optimistic concurrency property (etag or timestamp) ever be a part of domain?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Theoretically speaking, if we implement optimistic concurrency on Aggregate Root level (changing entities in AR changes version on AR) and lets say we use timestamp for version property (just for simplicity) - should timeline ever be a property on AR or should it be a part of read model on one side and on other (for example, updates) be a separate argument to application service like:

[pseudo]

```
public class AppService{
.
.
.
   public void UpdateSomething(UpdateModelDTO model, int timestamp)
   {
      repository.GetModel(model.Identifier);
      model.UpdateSomething(model.something);
      repository.ConcurrencySafeModelUpdate(model, timestamp);
   }
}
```

I see pros/cons for both but wondering which is by-the-book solution?

[UPDATE]

To answer question from @guillaume31, i expect usual scenario:

1. On read, version identifier is read and sent to client
2. On update, client sends back the identifier and repository returns some kind of an error if version identifier is not the same.

I don't know if its important but i want to leave responsibility for creating/updating version identifiers themselves to my database system.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if the Aggregate should know/care about that ts/version attribute/column/property?

Comment: yes, thats what i am asking.

Comment: Concurrent data access is somewhat orthogonal to DDD, so: no by-the-book solution. Can you be more specific about what you expect from application-level optimistic concurrency? What problem do you want it to solve?

Comment: @guillaume31 thanks for your question! I've updated my initial post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no by-the-book solution. Sometimes you'll already have a field in your aggregate that fits the role nicely (e.g. `LastUpdatedOn`), sometimes you can make it non-domain data. For performance reasons, it may be a good idea to select the field as part of the same query that fetches the aggregate though.

Some ORMs provide facilities to detect concurrency conflicts. Some DBMS's can create and update a version column automatically for you. You should probably look for guidelines about optimistic concurrency in your specific stack.

Comment: thank you for this answer! i must say that sounds most logical to me from performance/complexity point of view but i also heard some ddd purists saying just 'strictly no'. thats why i wanted to find out if there is some definite answer 'why not, actually'. I think i will go with version field in AR.

Comment: The history of DDD vs data access technology is full of compromises ;-) Being a purist comes at a cost. Like I said, you can try to leave your domain model untouched by these concurrency concerns but it may cost you in terms of performance, clarity, complexity, etc.

Comment: that makes perfect sense to me. thanks again for your thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

I assume, else you won't be asking this question, you are using your Domain model as Data model (i.e. Hibernate entity), then you have already introduced infrastructural concerns into your domain model, so I would suggest to go ahead and add the timestamp to AR.

Comment: No, i am not using it. I am actually asking before i do any of options as i'd just like to know whats proper ddd way of doing it.

Comment: Have a look at this http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/04/05/having-the-domain-model-separate-from-the-persistence-model/

Answer (score 0):

The Aggregate should not care about anything else but business related concerns. It should be pure, without any infrastructure concerns.

The `version` column in the database/persistence is an infrastructure concern so it should not be reflected in the Aggregate class from the Domain layer.

P.S. using timestamps for optimistic locking is weird; you would better use an integer that is incremented every time an Aggregate is mutated and that is expected to have the (loaded-version + 1) when a `save` is executed.

```
public void UpdateSomething(UpdateModelDTO model)
{
     (model, version) = repository.GetModel(model.Identifier);
     model.UpdateSomething(something);
     repository.ConcurrencySafeModelUpdate(model, version + 1);
}
```

Update: here is an [implementation example](https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cqrs/aggregates/EventSourcedAggregateRepository.java) in java.

Comment: timestamp was just for simplicity, of course its bad choice for OC. ok, i see your point. I have slightly different setup where db side generates versions but important is that AR has nothing to do with it. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: But how do you handle the same aggregate being changed concurrently? How to know which version was the aggregate when you are trying to save it in the infrastructure layer?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller you load the version when you rehydrate the aggregate then increment the version; if another instance has persisted before then the version + 1 is already in the database and the unique aggregate_Id+version would throw an error

Comment: But in your answer you mentioned that the Aggregate should not contain the version field. How do you know which version was it rehydrated if you don't put in it?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller The Aggregate should not know of such non-business things. You could store the loaded version in the respository, __next__ to the loaded aggregate instance

Comment: But how do you relate with the aggregate when its time to store it? If it’s not in object how do you know whoch aggregate was it the version from?

Comment: @JohnnyWiller the version is not in the Aggregate class as a property but is in the database table/collection; the Repository should have access to this data but it should not expose it to the Aggregate class.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu The problem with not passing version field to the aggregate when loading is if you receive concurrent requests, in that situation you would have 2 (or more) instances of that aggregate on memory, and would eventually save both to the DB, leading to data overwritten. The repository has access to the version field on the DB, but it can't know which version is the aggregate on memory referring to.

Comment: @JohnnyWiller the repository uses the Aggregate's version but it does simply not expose it to the business layer. It uses it internally, to detect concurrent updates.

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu If you can share a gist on the repo implementation would be better

Comment: @JohnnyWiller here is an example of an implementation of an event store (which is the persisting component for an event sourced application): https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-java-sql-event-store/blob/master/src/com/cqrs/sql_event_store/SqlEventStore.java

Comment: @JohnnyWiller here is an implementation in java of an aggregate repository: https://github.com/xprt64/cqrs-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/cqrs/aggregates/EventSourcedAggregateRepository.java