# DDD: separate model for domain and persistence

Tags: domain-driven-design

Assume we have separate models for Domain and Persistence, one domain model is stored as two persistence model, as given below.

```
class DomainEntity {
    property1;
    property2;
} 

class PersistenceEntity1 {
    domainProperty1;
    appProperty1;
}

class PersistenceEntity2 {
    domainPproperty2;
    appProperty2;
}
```

If you see the models there are some extra application properties in the persistence model which doesn't belong in the domain model, e.g. modifiedOn, modifiedBy etc...

Now my question is how to pass these values to the infrastructure layer, since the Repository interface also belongs to the Domain layer, we can't add these properties to its signature.

Comment: either don't mix domain and application layer attributes in one entity or you may consider of two repositories. one which is finds domain objects and one which acts on the application infos. but i would recommend to don't mix these attributes in one entity.

Comment: `Repository also belongs to the Domain layer` - how so? The Repository Interface: yes but the Repository Implementation: no

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu that's what I meant, interface. in implementation you can't have different signature, right?

Comment: You can't but you don't need to. Those additional attributes could be kept *hidden* in the Infrastructure layer.

Comment: (I edited your question: `since the Repository interface also belongs to the Domain layer`)

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu if you don't have a different signature then how will you pass these info to the infrastructure layer

Comment: But you don't pass them from the Domain layer if they are not part of the Domain layer, why would you need to do that?

Comment: You can pass them from the Application layer, for example.

Comment: Or even from the Infrastructure.

Comment: that's what I am asking, application layer will invoke `repository.update(domainEntity)` right, in infrastructure layer the domainEntity will be mapped to two persistenceEntities but it also needs few more information, how to get those info

Comment: Give me all the examples that you can think of. I.e. modifiedOn = the date of the modification

Comment: to start with modifiedBy is one info, I will add few more examples few minutes later, but how will you get modifiedBy

Comment: @wolverine you may be overengineering things here. As far as the examples you gave, we're talking about 2 fields that could perfectly fit in the domain model, not a bunch of evil low-level data that would force you to modify your domain model every time some infrastructure logic changes...

Answer (score 2):

The additional attributes that do not belong to the Domain can be added from the Infrastructure, for example from the Repository implementation. In this way, the Domain remain agnostic of infrastructure concerns.

The Repository implementation could get that data from the services that get injected. For example, if the Persistence model needs the current Authenticated user ID to be stored in the `modifiedBy` then the `AuthenticatedUserService` should be injected into the Repository implementation.

One simpler example is the `modifiedOn` that can be set to the Current system date, without any service injection.

As a pseudocode:

```
// Domain layer
class DomainEntity {
    property1;
    property2;
} 

// Infrastructure layer

class PersistenceEntity1 {
    domainProperty1;
    Date modifiedOn;
}

class PersistenceEntity2 {
    domainPproperty2;
    UserId modifiedBy;
}


class Repository {
    // dependency injection
    constructor(AuthenticatedUserService auth){ 
        this.auth = auth;
    }

    function save(DomainEntity d) {
       PersistenceEntity1 p1 = new PersistenceEntity1(d.property1, Date.current() );

       PersistenceEntity2 p21 = new PersistenceEntity1(d.property1, this.auth.getAuthenticatedUserId() );

       db1.save(p1);
       db2.save(p2);
    }
}
```

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49321466/1448660) question you answered, you are passing the timestamp but it doesn't belong in the signature of repository interface. how will you handle this?

Comment: @wolverine that `timestamp` is not used, it is a remain from the OPs question. it should be deleted.

Comment: doesn't matter,even if take integer as a version control field then also the application service has to pass this to the infrastructure layer, you won't be able get it using injected service like `AuthenticatedUserService `

Comment: @wolverine 1/2: Yes, indeed but that is part of the signature, it is something that the Repository needs in order to use optimistic concurency. Also, it is something that is opaque to the client code. Even more, it is something that can even be kept as a private property, an implementation detail.

Comment: @wolverine 2/2: For example, when the Repository loads an Aggregate from the persistence it can store the `version` as a private property onto itself (in a map of Aggregates and their versions); then, before the Aggregate it is persisted, it can lookup that version; in this way you can eliminate version from the Interface signature.

Comment: @wolverine In that answer I put version on the signature because it was relevant in that context; in your context it is not.

Comment: 1/2 I think you will agree that concurrency is an application concern not the domain, so we drop the idea of having the version number in the signature

Comment: @wolverine  indeed, not a Domain concern but I would put it in the Infrastructure, as an implementation detail, not in the Application.

Comment: 2/2 then come to the idea of private property in the repository itself, the same aggregate was read by two different users and if you have a map in the implementation then it will contain what, the user id, aggregate id and version id. then the same user  can have multiple session then your map need to have session id as well, then what about stateless application, the complexity keeps growing if you just store the version in the infrastructure instead of application layer passing it. is my concern clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167248/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-wolverine).